# Is it possible to make custom android media routes?

Tags: android, a2dp

I'd like to implement my own media route, like A2DP, but instead it will use wifi (like airplay).

Is there a way to do this? Android certainly has the infrastructure (`MediaRouter`, `AudioManager`, etc), but I can't find my way through the (virtually undocumented) code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make the route available to other applications, it will probably require an OS-level change. So feel free if you want to compile the source and develop your own custom ROM.

If you are just trying to make your own app use a "custom media route", then you simply have to implement it... e.g. open a socket over WiFi.

Comment: Well of course I can do my own streaming. That isn't quite the same though is it?

Comment: Truely. Well if you are looking to modify the OS, you might start by looking at /media/java/android/media/AudioService.java -- this seems to be the glue between Java and the native audio server.